# Unknown Technologies for Web Forms

Tags: php, javascript, css, ajax, jquery

I am trying to get to grips with various forms of web design and build. I have looked around and still cannot get a useful answer on what technology is best to create a Dynamic Submission form (that doesn't look like crap). 
I want to build a sumitable form that is aesthetically pleasing. I have planned and sorted out that I will use PHP and AJAX so it can be interactive but I am lost on what technology to use to actually code/script the design of the form. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

- If anyone who reads this uses Virgin Media as their internet provider and they use their card details form online, that is my ultimate goal to make the form similar too (with different questions and submission details, but that isn't important). The look is what I am after.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot on the Virgin Media form?

Comment: check out formly. I love it for styling forms (link: http://thrivingkings.com/formly/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are on the right track actually.

- for aesthetics, you should research more about designing in HTML/CSS
- JS is used for the dynamic user interface
- PHP and AJAX are all that's needed for a dynamic form submission
- google is your friend. go ask him.

other than that, it's up to your imagination and originality how you implement it.

Comment: The actual form layout is in XHTML/CSS, but you can alter it right? As every time I have created a form it comes out 'blocky and horrible'. Another thing I want to do, not mandatoy but what would I use to make it pop out of the Web Page, like an annoying pop-up but so details can be filled in and submitted without the user being able to select anything on the original web page? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @PinkAndFluffy yes, its HTML/CSS. there are a lot of techniques how to make it "non-blocky". and the"focused pop-up where you can't do anything besides on that pop-up, is called a "modal window"

Comment: Thanks, will have a deeper look into that. Cheers for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you would need to use html and css to actually build the form.

Javascript to possibly validate the form on the persons browser (client side)

php would submit and send the form.

If you like the look of the virgin media form you can find out how it was done by using developer tools on chrome (f12 on a windows machine, cmd, alt and I on a mac) or firebug pluign on firefox. Others are available but these are two of the best. This wll show you the html mark up the css and how it all works.

Comment: That's the same as 'view source' right? Most of it appears to be hidden all I know is that they have used JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have some examples of interactive forms: http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-jquery-tutorials-for-working-with-html-forms

Answer (score -4):

Your best bet will be with ASP.NET.
Its easy to set up and the software is easy to use and is free.
You should use Microsoft web developer express.
http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express
You will have the choice to code in c# or visual basic , c# will be the beter choice.
ASP.net is the new generation of website development.

Comment: How can that be best bet with 99% of easy to build web examples are in PHP on the server?

Comment: What are you saying? , there are thousands of simple tutorials available.

Comment: ASP.net is 100 times more powerfull than Php or ajax , plus ajax can be coded into asp.net.

Comment: Where does this user need power? And how can you compare asp to ajax?
I have done internet related coding since 1996 and I would not ever consider asp.net for a beginner. I also would never consider it for my own sites since it is a lot more complex than PHP and MySql will ever be. If you are already a C# programmer, by all means, stay with asp.net, but if not, the learning curve is plain silly for a non-programmer.